# How to correctly use Mockito's verify on a spring @Service test

Tags: kotlin, mockito, spring-test

I have this service (all in kotlin):

```
@Service
class MyService {

  fun getSomeString(): String = "test"
}
```

And this integration test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka // used on some kafka tests
class BasicTests {
```

and method:

```
@Test
fun `test method count`() {
    // here I have a kafka producer sending a message to a topic that ends up 
    // calling myService.getSomeString via @KafkaListener from other services
    verify(someObjectRelatedToMyService, atLeast(1)).getSome()
}
```

In the place of `someObjectRelatedToMyService` I tried to use

```
@Autowired
lateinit var myService: MyService
```

But then I got `Argument passed to verify() is of type MyService and is not a mock!`

But when I use

```
@Mock
lateinit var myMock: MyService
```

I get `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

And actually, to me it makes sense, since my mock wasn't called, but my real service at the application was.

Is it possible to count method calls from my real object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [spy on the real object](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) to count method calls on it like this:

```
@Test
fun `test method count`() {
    Mockito.spy(someObjectRelatedToMyService)
    verify(someObjectRelatedToMyService, atLeast(1)).getSome()
}
```

As you can see, the only thing you have to do is to call the [*spy*](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-) method which enables tracking interactions with the target object.

When adding this call before the verify method, you should not get the error anymore that the object is not a mock.

Answer (score 0):

[Posting here since no rep to comment] Have you tried using a @Spy? Then you could specify which methods to mock and which methods to call. I supposed you can also apply Mockito.verify on spies...

Comment: I didn't understand the need for a partial mock offered by `@Spy`

Comment: Because you are trying to verify the usage of a non-mock object that is being called, and when you mock the same object, you cannot call the real method. Spying it will allow you to mock some methods of the object, while allowing you to verify the usage of the real ones.